# ASP.NET - Could not find stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've been searching the depths of the internet and all the solutions I found did not solve this problem.

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express with SQL Server 2008, using VB.

I am trying to execute a stored procedure to insert some data coming from a textbox control to a database, if the id doesn't exist it inserts both the id given in the textbox and the current date (time_scanned_in), if the id exists already, it will insert the current datetime in the `[time_scanned_out]` column, if all 3 fields in the db are full, it will return `@message = 1`.

Here is the sql stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertDateTime
@barcode_id nchar(20),
@message char(1) = 0 Output
AS
BEGIN
    if not exists(select * from tblWork where barcode_id = @barcode_id)
    begin
        INSERT INTO [tblWork] ([barcode_id], [time_scanned]) VALUES (@barcode_id, GetDate())
    end
    else if exists(select * from tblWork where barcode_id = @barcode_id AND time_scanned_out IS NOT NULL )
    begin
        SET @message=1
    end
    else if exists(select * from tblWork where barcode_id = @barcode_id AND time_scanned_out IS NULL)
    begin
        UPDATE [tblWork] SET [time_scanned_out] = GetDate() WHERE [barcode_id] = @barcode_id
    end
RETURN @message
end
```

If I execute this (by right clicking on the SP), it works flawlessly and returns the values when all fields have been filled.

But when executed through the vb code, no such procedure can be found, giving the error in the title.

Here is the vb code:

```
Dim opconn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(opconn)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim returnValue As Object

cmd.CommandText = "InsertDateTime"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()
With cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@barcode_id", TextBox.Text))
End With
With cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@message", SqlDbType.Char, 1, Label3.Text))
End With

returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Note, I haven't done the code for the return part yet, will do that once I get it to locate the SP.

Tried listing all objects with the sys.objects.name for each of the databases in a gridview, it listed everything but the stored procedure I want.

Why is this, any ideas?  Would be much appreciated, spent hours trying to find a solution.
If anyone needs any more code or information feel free to ask.

Comment: Try `cmd.CommandText = "dbo.InsertDateTime"`

Comment: Tried it many times with lots of different prefixes including that one, tried my user name and everything, exact same error.

Comment: are you sure you are connecting the the database which has this proc ?

Comment: Try using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` (instead of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`) - since your stored procedure isn't returning exactly one row, exactly one column (like a `SELECT COUNT(*)..` would), `ExecuteScalar` is the wrong method to call. Also: the parameter for `@message` needs to be set to `Parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output` to be able to get back what it returns...

Comment: SP is in wrong database? Permissions are not sufficient to view/execute SP with integrated account (ASPNET user/ IIS)?

Comment: I only have just the one database, and I already have multiple gridviews getting data from the tables so I'm almost certain the connection string isn't at fault.

marc_s, tried that, no luck :/ thank you though.

@kakridge, I can certainly view and execute the SP fine, and it's not in the wrong db as outlined above.

Comment: You are viewing and executing the SP with YOUR account, not the IIS account.  Just to explicitly remove this as a cause, add the name of the database to your connection string.  Then recreate the SP with a USE <database name> and DROP/CREATE.

Comment: Also, look and see what accounts have execute permission on the SP.

Comment: @kakridge Modified the connection string.  Tried creating a new SP with the USE statement and it doesn't like it, if I place it before the CREATE it complains that the SP must start with CREATE or ALTER, and if I put it after the CREATE statement it says 'A USE statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.'

Comment: Try this: USE DATABASENAME; 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ...

Comment: Had already done that yep, same error, the syntax highlighting didn't appear on the word GO either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated the whole project with a whole new database, copied all the same code, and now it all works flawlessly!  Still have no idea what was wrong, but thank you all, you were all prompt and knowledgable.

Here was the final VB code for anyone who's interested:

```
Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(opconn)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = myConnection
cmd.CommandText = "InsertTimes"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", OleDbType.Integer)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode_id", TextBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters("@message").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Try
    myConnection.Open()
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim returnMessage As String = cmd.Parameters("@message").Value
    If returnMessage = 1 Then
        label_confirmation.Text = "Record successfully submitted!"
        TextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf returnMessage = 2 Then
        label_confirmation.Text = "A finish time already exists for the record '" & TextBox.Text & "', would you like to override the finish time anyway?"
        button_yes.Visible = True
        button_no.Visible = True
    ElseIf returnMessage = 3 Then
        label_confirmation.Text = "Record submitted, work operation status complete!"
        TextBox.Text = ""
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    label_confirmation.Text = ex.ToString()
Finally
    myConnection.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

try cmd.parameters.clear() first and then start adding parameters in cmd object. also instead of cmd.executescaler(), try cmd.executenonquery or cmd.executeReader()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode_id",  TextBox.Text)
 SqlParameter prmOut = cmd.Parameters.Add("@message",SqlDbType.Char, 1)
 prmOut.Value = Label3.Text
 prmOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

 returnValue = prmOut.Value.ToString()
```

Comment: I take it 'prmOut' is declared the same way I declared 'returnValue'?

Comment: This should replace everything from your first `With` to the `returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() `